# Set default application for particular file types in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, defaults

I use nautilus as file manager and would like to use Vim instead of Gedit to edit my text files. Many files (log files, empty files, …) are already opened with Vim, however not all of them, e.g. tex files and XML files are still opened with Gedit.

`update-alternatives  --get-selections | grep edit` yields

```
editor                auto     /usr/bin/vim.gnome
gnome-text-editor     manual   /usr/bin/vim.gnome
readline-editor       auto     /usr/bin/rlwrap
```

and I have also set the `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` environment variables to point to vim.

Although the questions is about changing the default applicatin for *any* file type, it is fine to respond with a solution that just addresses the mentioned problem changing the default editor, since that is what bothers me at the moment.

EDIT:

The answer of “hesse” worked for most file types, but not for all. For instance Makefiles are still opened with Gedit. `file --mime-type Makefile` returns `text/plain`, which is already included in `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list`. However `file --mime-type somefile` also returns `text/plain` but is opened with Vim.

I use Debian unstable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look in `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` under `[Default Applications]`. There you should set the `text/plain` to point to the `.desktop` entry for `vim`, which is usually located in `/usr/share/applications/`. E.g:

```
text/plain=gvim.desktop
```

Comment: Can I specify a wildcard? `text=gvim.desktop` or `text/*=gvim.desktop` does not work. I want to cover *all* text files.

Answer (score 13):

The key is File|Properties.  Choose this menu item with a file of the target filetype selected, go to "Open With" tab and press "Reset."  Then select an application and press "Set as Default." Kitchen tested on Nautilus 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

To change a file association in [GNOME Files](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Apps/Files), e.g. for `.txt` files:

1. either

   - right-click on your `.txt` file and select `Properties`, or
   - select your `.txt` file by left-clickin on it and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
     [image: GNOME Files file context menu]
2. select the `Open With` tab
3. select your preferred application
4. select `Set as default` (or `Reset` to use the default application)
   [image]
5. click on `⨯` to close the `Properties` window

Comment: This is duplicating an existing answer, but adds pictures.  Instead of providing duplicated answers, you could suggest improvements to existing answers if you think they lack something.